# d3 get all nodes of tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I try to keep this as short as I can:

In the snippet I have a Json which represents a tree. With the help of d3 I try to get all child nodes of the root as an Array. For that I use the function "nodes".

The Problem is that my children key is called "_children" instead of "children". I try to find a good solution to tell the nodes function to check "*children" instead of "children". If I remove the "*" of all children keys it works.

```js
var json = {"_name":"root","_children":[{"_name":"Application","_children":[{"_name":"Application Heap","_children":[],"_color":"#0000ff", "MEMORY":20},{"_name":"Other","_children":[],"_color":"#000055","MEMORY":30},{"_name":"Statement Heap","_children":[],"_color":"","MEMORY":40}]}]};

console.log(json);

// tell d3 that my children key is "_children"
var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
    .children(function(d) { return d._children; })
    .value(function(d) { return d.MEMORY; });

// With this line I try to get all child nodes of the root element
var nodes = treemap.nodes(json)
    .filter(function(d) {return !d._children; });
    
console.log(json);  // d3 sets the value and everything else correct
console.log(nodes); // for some reason I get an empty array
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (but not the one I want) is to rename the field recursive like that at first:

```
var renameKeys=function(obj){
    if(obj._children){
        obj.children=obj._children;
        delete obj._children;
        obj.children.forEach(renameKeys);
    }
return obj;
};
```